# How to clear events when manually bootstraping ng-grid in an Angularjs Single Page application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-grid

I'm working on an hybrid SPA with many angularJS modules in an existing application.
When manually Bootstraping ng-grid twice or more, 'ngGridEventStartCellEdit' events are multiplied each times the module is re-bootstraped.
It is like if DOM events are always bound even after leaving the module.

I tried to catch $destroy event like it :

```
elm.bind('$destroy', function(event) {
   elm.off('blur');
   elm.off('mousedown');
   elm.off('keydown');
});
```

But it does nothing.

How could I do to clear all events bindings when I leave my bootstraped module?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery docs here:

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements.  Also, try using the target of the event, like so:

```
element.bind('$destroy', function (event) {
   event.target.off();
});
```